# missing SIGINT from script?

Tags: c++, c, bash, shell, signals

I am experiencing very strange behaviour when I attempt to send SIGINT from a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
./executable 6 &
PID=$!
sleep 2
kill -s SIGINT $PID
sleep 2
if wait $PID; then
    echo "FAILURE"
else
    echo "SUCCESS"
fi
```

to an executable compiled from C++ code (`g++ source.spp --std=c++11 -o executable`) that has no signal handler set:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(std::atoi(argv[1])));
    std::cout << std::endl << "FINISHED" << std::endl;
}
```

The process does not get terminated (I get "FAILURE", then "FINISHED").

This works completely as expected, when I:

- send SIGINT from command line to background process
- press CTRL-C when process is in foreground
- set default signal handler explicitly: `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);`

I can reproduce it on different distros with different compilers (for example, Ubuntu 20.04 with Bash 5.0.16, GCC 9.3.0). Ideally I would like to understand what is going on, but for a time being I would be happy with a workaround that does not require changes to an executable.

Comment: Maybe from a different site, but take a look at it https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485630/process-started-by-script-does-not-receive-sigint

Answer (score 0):

@MohithReddy thank you! Your hint has led me to an answer that explains why it happening (process started in a background from a script has SIG_IGN for SIGINT and SIGQUIT): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478563/sleep-wait-and-ctrlc-propagation/478697#478697

Now I only need to find a workaround that would let me run an executable with SIGINT set to SIG_DFL by default.

Comment: Turn on job control with `set -m` before running `./executable &`?